# Javascript Multidimensional Array/Hashtable

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
storeChildren : function(coreid, data) {
  $.each(data, function(id, type) {
    $.core.children[coreid] = {};
    $.core.children[coreid]['id'] = id;
    $.core.children[coreid]['type'] = type;
  });
}
```

($.core.children is an object)

I want the resulting array/object (I prefer objects) to look like this (excuse my PHP pseudocode):

```
array(coreid => array(id=>type, id=>type, id=>type));
```

I know I am overwriting $.core.children[coreid] each time I run the loop I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I'd use an object instead `var obj = { key: value, key: value, ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your 'id's are unique, the following should work; is this what you're after?

```
storeChildren : function(coreid, data) {
  $.core.children[coreid] = {};
  $.each(data, function(id, type) {
    $.core.children[coreid][id] = type;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
init: function() {
    $.core.children = []; // instantiate array
},

storeChildren : function(coreid, data) {

    $.each(data, function(id, type) {
        $.core.children[coreid] = {id : type};
    });
}
```

Instantiate the object elsewhere in your code, then you won't kill the associative array/object each time.  The above example also uses an object inside your array instead of an array, the result, in JSON notation, looks as follows:

```
[ {key,value} , {key,value} , {key,value} , ...]
```

The coreid is the index of the array.